# Summing random vectors

Tags: probability

N indepedent unit vectors of uniformly random directions are added in R^3. What is the expected  squared length of the resulting vector?

Comment: $N$. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: You @did it again -- a one-letter answer :-)

Comment: @joriki: [Oops](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvtDHH_IfP8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the mean of the unit vectors is $0$, the mean of the squares of the lengths of the vectors is the variance of the vectors: the variance is the mean of the squares minus the square of the mean.

The mean of the square of length of one vector is $1$ (it is always $1$). Since the vectors are independent, the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances, so the variance of the sum of $N$ unit vectors is $N$.

Thus, as did claims in his comment, the expected squared length of the sum of $N$ uniformly directed, random unit vectors is $N$.